# Svelte using input type=range with bind:value and max: slider shown wrong when value and max change

Tags: input, range, svelte

Using Svelte, for input range (slider) changing bind:value AND max both from  10 to 20, slider shows wrong position while values are correct ? 
I assume I'm making a mistake somewhere ( or is it a bug ?) Who can tell...

As it seems the value is not rerendered after max changed, I could solve this by using a timeout of 10ms on the value re-assignment. I think this alows the slider to adjust to max first and then to value.
The actual value and max are correct.
Example is in svelte REPL

```
<script>
    let value=10;
    let max=10;

    function change() {
        value=20;
        max=20;
    }
</script>

<h1 on:click={change}>Click to Change</h1>
<input type=range min=0 max={max} bind:value={value}>
<br>
Value {value} of {max} max.
```

Comment: I had the same problem when creating [this](https://2pha.github.io/svelte-three-shaders/public/), I never did find a fix.

Comment: You just need to add ` value={value}` to your `input` tag. `bind` sends the value out of the element. Adding an attribute sends the value into the element.

Comment: You can also remove `={value}` from your `bind`. It will implicitly search for a variable of the same name. `<input type=range min=0 max={max} bind:value value={value} />`

Comment: I've opened an issue — I think this is a bug that should be fixed https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3857

Answer (score 3):

As described in the comments by @Benny, you actually need to add `"value={value}"` to update the `input` element itself.

And BTW, if the `bind:` name matches the value, you can use a shorthand, as described [here](https://svelte.dev/docs#bind_element_property) in the docs. so this will be the solution:

```html
<input type=range min=0 max={max} bind:value value={value} />
```

[Updated REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/079cb441f1574c85917081726d2be18b?version=3.12.1)

Comment: Tnx for your answer, It solves the wrong indicator, but my variable value does not get updated anymore causing a new workaround.

Comment: Your answer is only half right. He does need to add `value={value}`, but he needs to keep `bind:value`.